# KonvaJS - Font Scaling in Group of Text Nodes

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have a group of text nodes, and I'd like to be able to resize the group using transformer, but have the font size of each internal text node remain the same. Default behavior is transformer will scale the font size up or down during resize event.

[Here is an example of what I mean, the font is scaled up in size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr3rI.png)

How would it be possible to maintain the font size of each text node within a Konva group when resizing using the transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be hard to adjust font size of text inside a scaled group.

You can try to set "reversed" scale to text no, so the text is not stretched. For example, if you group `scaleX` is `0.5`, you can set `scaleX` for text to `2`. In that case, absolute scale will be `1`. Then you can manually adjust `fontSize` of the text to fit available space.

But I think there is a much simpler option. Instead of attaching transformer into the group directly, you can attach it into an invisible rectangle. Then just use the size of that rectangle to adjust positions of group elements. So, you will avoid changing the scale of the group and the math will be much simpler.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// generate table
const table = new Konva.Group();
layer.add(table);

const ROWS = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
  const row = new Konva.Group()
  table.add(row);
  row.add(new Konva.Text({
    text: 'Row ' + i,
    name: 'text',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  }))
  row.add(new Konva.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 50, 0],
    y: 11,
    stroke: 'black'
  }));
}

// update size from passed params
function updateTable({x, y, width, height }) {
  table.setAttrs({ x, y });
  
  const rowHeight = height / table.children.length;
  table.children.forEach((rowGroup, index) => {
    rowGroup.y(rowHeight * index);
    rowGroup.findOne('Text').setAttrs({
      height: rowHeight
    })
    rowGroup.findOne('Line').setAttrs({
      points: [0, 0, width, 0],
      y: rowHeight
    });
  })
}
updateTable({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});

// create resizing target
const resizer = new Konva.Rect({
  ...table.getClientRect(),
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
});
layer.add(resizer);

// create transformer
const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  nodes: [resizer],
  ignoreStroke: true,
  boundBoxFunc: (oldBox, newBox) => {
    if (newBox.width < 5 || newBox.height < 5) {
      return oldBox;
    }
    return newBox;
  }
})
layer.add(tr);

// handle resizing
resizer.on('transform', () => {
  updateTable({
    x: resizer.x(),
    y: resizer.y(),
    width: resizer.width() * resizer.scaleX(),
    height: resizer.height() * resizer.scaleY(),
  })
})
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^8/konva.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
```